# Outlook Add-In: How can I respond to changes to AppointmentItems?

Tags: outlook, system.reactive, outlook-addin

I'd like to write an add-in that responds to events in the calendar - when `AppointmentItems` get added/moved/deleted, start times change, etc.  I know I can get the currently selected items via `Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection` and can iterate through them, but how can I attach/detach events to those items without leaking memory all over the place?  As soon as selection changes, I've lost my reference to the previously selected items, haven't I?

*As an aside, I'd like to use Reactive Extensions for this, if it's appropriate (and I don't know that it is). It seems like I should be able to create an `Observable.FromEventPattern(...)` to aggregate the stream of events from the items into a sequence, but again... I'm flummoxed as to where to start.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Items.ItemAdd/ItemChange/ItemRemove` events. Items collection can be retrieved the MAPIFolder.Items property.

Comment: So ... I'm wondering how to get the name of the property that changed.  I haven't subscribed to the PropertyChanged event for the item - and it seems that by the time Items.ItemChange has fired, it's too late for Item.PropertyChanged anyway... suggestions?

Comment: You will have to assume that everything has changed.